# Unable to select from Dropdown (<input type="hidden" value="person">) using Selenium VBA

Tags: html, vba, selenium

I am working on a code to select from a dropdown list. I need to Select Keywords from the Dropdown. The value for People is Person. The value for Keywords is keyword. My current code is this:

```
.FindElementByXPath("//input[@value='person']").Click  
.FindElementByXPath("//input[@value='person']").SendKeys("keyword")
```

But this code does not open the dropdown list. Also when I run my code, I get `ElementNotVisibleError` and `Element Not Interactable`.

I have checked multiple sources but I couldn't find anything specific for VBA/Selenium with only input type and value.

HTML Code looks like this:

```
<div class="jss87 jss91 select__select___3WhZb search-filters__select___3d4-W" data-qa-id="entity-search-filters">
 <div class="jss82">
   <div class="jss83 jss84 jss95" aria-pressed="false" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-haspopup="true">People</div>
    <input type="hidden" value="person">
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="select__iconComponent___IoeS4"><defs><path id="chevron-down-small-a" d="M3.6125,4.925 C3.5,4.875 3.4,4.8 3.3,4.7 L0.3,1.7 C-0.1,1.3 -0.1,0.7 0.3,0.3 C0.7,-0.1 1.3,-0.1 1.7,0.3 L4,2.6 L6.3,0.3 C6.5,0.1 6.7,0 7,0 C7.3,0 7.5,0.1 7.7,0.3 C8.1,0.7 8.1,1.3 7.7,1.7 L4.7,4.7 C4.4,5 3.9875,5.075 3.63125,4.925 L3.6125,4.925 Z"></path></defs><use class="theme-variable:palette.primary.main" transform="translate(8 10)" xlink:href="#chevron-down-small-a"></use></svg></div></div>
```

Comment: Are you launching browser in full screen mode ?

Comment: No. It's opening at its default.

Comment: can you make it bigger and see if that resolves your issue ?

Comment: I just did that and it did not solve the problem. I am thinking it might be because the input type is 'hidden' and not 'text'. But I couldn't find a way to change that attribute.

Comment: Is it possible to share the Link.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but I can't share the link. I already posted the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I used the following codes.

The first line opens the list. The second one selects the "Keywords" option.

```
    .FindElementByXPath("//*[text() = 'People']").Click
    .FindElementByXPath("//li[@data-value='keyword']").Click
```

I hope this can help someone else who is having the same-ish problem.